# MPI runtime-error:unable to read the cmd header on the pmi context, error = -1

Tags: runtime, mpi, mpich

I have a poblem with mpich2. 
I've written program in C++ using MPI.
The program has been compiled successfully, but when I try to run the program I get an

```
 error:unable to read the cmd header on the pmi context, error = -1.
```

I have tried to reinstall the mpich, but the problem wasn't solved.

Does someone know how to solve the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: This looks pertinent: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.parallel.mpi/2008-02/msg00014.html

Comment: I have seen this website, but there is no answer for my question there.

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov is it happening on Windows? Which version of mpich2 do you have (`mpirun --version`)? Does it happen when the program runs with a single process? Is this the only error message or are there other errors?

Comment: it doesn't matter with how many porcess program runs, the error is the same. For example if I try to run in 4 process  4 previously told errors are occored, in 3 - 3. So yes but there is no any other errors.  mpirun --version doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You have more than one mpiexec.exe files from different vendors in you system. For example, one from `c:\program files\mpich2\bin` and one from `c:\program files\microsoft hpc pack 2008 r2\bin`.

Try to disable one of them.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Instead of "disabling" one of the executables you can just specify the full path to the correct mpiexec.exe, e.g. "C:\Program Files\MPICH2\bin\mpiexec.exe".

Answer (score 0):

In my case this type of message was caused by AVAST shield. I disabled it and everything started to work smoothly.